# Is the old version of orbot dangerous?

Tags: orbot

I have an old model of android device (not smart"phone") and I've used orbot and orfox app to browse through deepweb.

One day I found out that my orbot app is outdated as I was warned by a deepweb site that said my orbot was an old version.

So I tried to update orbot on playstore, but I couldn't since my device was too old to be supported (It is Gingerbread and no updated is released).

I can browse almost every deepweb sites, and the torcheck.org says that i've connected to tor though.

Is it that dangerous to use the outdated orbot app?

The latest version that supports mine is v14.1.4

Thanks

Comment: When you start Orbot, which Tor version is shown in the log?

Comment: Have you tried [FDroid](https://fdroid.org/)? It has the Guardian Projects own repo builtin and it *looks* like there are newer versions of [Orbot which support Gingerbread](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.torproject.android) (>=2.3). Specifically, I seems that the "`noPIE`" versions are there for older android versions. It's likely that [PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables) is what your android version doesn't support. Android >=5.0 uses *only* PIE so it breaks backwards compatibility.

Comment: It's using Tor 0.2.5.10 which is *not* within the recommended set for clients, so I would consider this dangerous. I'll try to formulate a proper answer, although I think the above and the fact that Gingerbread is probably full of foreverdays (thanks android software ecosystem!) should be reason enough. tl;dr - You will use Tor, but it might be exploitable.